# How can I relate the idea of having the minimum value of a function defined by x,y and z and planes and matrices

Tags: vectors, lagrange-multiplier

A function is given as f(x,y,z)=2x^(2)+y^(2)+5z^(2) then the question is to find the  minimum value of this function on the plane x+2y+3z=1

I can see that the given function has always non negative value and so the minimum value is 0 but since the point (0,0,0) is not on the plane, I took g(x,y,z)=x+2y+3z and I calculated the value of f when g=1 and ∇f=λ∇g that is,
(4x,2y,10z)=λ(1,2,3) with this I found that the function has its minimum value on the plane at the coordinate (5/63,20/63,6/63) and that corresponds to a functional value of 10/63.
Is there any other way of getting the solution using matrices or the concept of planes and 3d vectors? This question was at the end of a chapter on 3d vectors and matrices in calculus 1 and so I think I am not supposed to use Lagrange multipliers. I would be grateful.

Comment: Here's a trick. Let $\alpha=x$, $\beta=\frac y2$, $\gamma =\frac z3$. So, $f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=2\alpha^2+\frac14\beta^2+\frac59\gamma^2$. Since the plane becomes $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1$, which is symmetric on the three variables. So, $f$ is minimized when $2\alpha^2=\frac14\beta^2=\frac59\gamma^2$.

Comment: Consider finding the minimum of $g(y,z)=f(1-2y-3z,y,z)$ if Lagrange multipliers are not allowed, it's the same difficulcy task as finding the minimum of $f$.

Comment: @DonThousand sadly I can't apply such trick to the Iran 96 inequality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a pretty standard "Lagrange Multiplier" problem.  At a max or min of f(x,y,z) subject to constraint g(x,y,z)= constant, the gradients of f and g will be parallel: $\nabla f= \lambda \nabla g$ for some constant, $\lambda$ (the "Lagrange Multiplier").

Here, $f(x,y,z)= 2x^2+ y^2+ 3z^2$ so $\nabla f= 4x\vec{i}+ 2y\vec{j}+ 10z\vec{k}$ and $g(x,y,z)= x+ 2y+ 3z$ so $\nabla g= \vec{i}+ 2\vec{j}+ 3\vec{k}$.

We must have $4x\vec{i}+ 2y\vec{j}+ 10z\vec{k}= \lambda(\vec{i}+ 2\vec{j}+ 3\vec{k})$ so we must have $4x= \lambda$, $2y= 2\lambda$, and $10z= 3\lambda$.  Since a value for $\lambda$ is not necessary for a solution to this kind of problem, often the best way to solve these equations is to **divide** one equation by the other.

For example, if we divide the first equation by the second, we get $\frac{4x}{2y}= \frac{1}{2}$ and then have y= 4x.  If we divide the first equation by the third, $\frac{4x}{10z}= \frac{1}{3}$ and then z= (6/5)x.  Then the constraint becomes x+ 2y+ 3z= x+ 8x+ 18/5x= (63/5)x= 1 so x= 5/63.  Then y= 4(5/63)= 20/63 and z= (6/5)(5/63)= 6/63= 2/21.

Check my arithmetic!

Comment: That is correct. But I was wondering if there is another way of getting the solution without using Lagrange multipliers.